# I want to validate my flutter form with iconButton and go to the homepage. But i couldn't link the button with the page i want to display

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I wrote some code that display a form. The submit button is IconButton type. I want to go to the homepage of my app by clicking it but this return me an error.

this is for a flutter form

```
Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 80.0,
                    icon: Image.asset("images/send.png"),
                    onPressed: () {}
```

i expected to link the submit button by clicking or pressing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Route from one page to another you need to add routes in materialapp widget.Example given below:

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Firstpage(),
  routes: <String,WidgetBuilder>{
    "/SecondPage": (BuildContext context) => new SecondScreen()
  }  
)
```

then on your code simply put :

```
Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 80.0,
                icon: Image.asset("images/send.png"),
                onPressed: () {
                     Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/SecondPage")
               }
           )
)
```

**Hope this helps.**